# "sqlexception could not find stored procedure" - C# Execute Store Procedure in SqlServer without parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

right now I have this method to execute the store procedure:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteProcedureNoParams(string connectionStringName, string procedureName)
    {
        using (DbCommand sprocCmd = SqlDB(connectionStringName).GetStoredProcCommand(procedureName))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (IDataReader sprocReader = SqlDB(connectionStringName).ExecuteReader(sprocCmd))
            {
                dt.Load(sprocReader);
                // DisplayRowValues(sprocReader);
            }

            return dt;

        }
    }

private static SqlDatabase sqlDB;

    public static SqlDatabase SqlDB(string connectionString)
    {
        if (sqlDB == null)
        {
            sqlDB = CreateConnection(connectionString);
        }
        return sqlDB;
    }

    private static SqlDatabase CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
        {
            // Create the default Database object from the factory.
            // The actual concrete type is determined by the configuration settings.
            return factory.CreateDefault() as SqlDatabase;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a Database object from the factory using the connection string name.
            return factory.Create(connectionString) as SqlDatabase;
        }

    }
```

Now, the error that i'm getting is that it cannot find my store procedure ("sqlexception could not find stored procedure").
I tested the connection String in the web config and it also working properly.

it fails in the IDataReader call.

could please anyone help me with this issue?

p.s. - I'm trying to create a method that executes a store procedure without giving it any parameters and retrieving it as DataTable.

Comment: "the error that i'm getting is that it cannot find my store procedure" Post the EXACT exception, i.e. copy-paste its text. Also, please fix the title of your question so it reflects the actual issue you're having.

Comment: done.
please tell me if this is more suitable? @BCdotWEB

Comment: Do you have a typo in the stored procedure name? Are you actually connecting to the correct database? Are you qualifying the stored procedure owner (ie dbo..)  It's hard to see what the problem is but the clue is in the exception - SQL server can't find what you are asking for.

Comment: the store procedure name is correct - I tested it in the sql server (with the exact string). 
and i'm connecting to the correct database.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I managed to resolve the issue.
the problem was with `SqlDatabase sqlDB;`
it saved an old connection string I just needed a to update the constructor to look like this:

```
 public static SqlDatabase SqlDB(string connectionString)
    {
        if (sqlDB == null || sqlDB.ConnectionString != connectionString)
        {
            sqlDB = CreateConnection(connectionString);
        }
        return sqlDB;
    }
```

and it worked like a charm. 
thank for any one who helped me.